# Windows 2003 drops static IP address

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip-address

Our web server in the past day has dropped two static IP addresses.  When they are dropped, they are still listed in the IP Properties, but if you perform a "cmd" -> "route PRINT" they are not.  Removing the IP from the IP properties, and adding them back corrects this, but any idea on how they are dropping?  There are no helpful entries in the system logs.

Comment: Since @Joe has indicated that this might somehow be hardware/driver-related, I am curious: what make/model of integrated or add-on NIC is this issue affecting, and what is the driver version? Same question goes to Joe.

Comment: try arp -d * Could be something funky going on with your DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar scenario on a 2003 server we have set up.  I ended up having to replace the NIC to correct the issue.  I would not see any entries in the system events, the ip address would just switch from static to dhcp.

Swapping out the NIC solved the issue for me.

Comment: Swapping it out with an identical device, or with one using of a different make/chipset/hardware revision/driver/nvram content?

Comment: It was swapped with an identical device from a decommissioned server.  This was a dell server btw, and while this is the first time I've run into nic issues on server, it is not the first time I've run into nic issues with dell hardware.  I have had several nic issues with Optiplex 740s, especially when running linux.

Comment: @Miles Erickson I can't comment yet directly to your response.  Just to be honest, this was a couple of years ago so I could not honestly say what the make and driver was of the device.  I want to say they were Broadcom NetXtreme cards, but I'm pulling that from old memory.